# Unable to install all kodi dependencies on Raspbian 8

Tags: raspbian, kodi, packages

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian 8.
I would like to install kodi but when I type `sudo apt-get install kodi`, here is what I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libgif7
Suggested packages:
  kodi-pvr-mythtv kodi-pvr-vuplus kodi-pvr-vdr-vnsi kodi-pvr-njoy kodi-pvr-nextpvr
  kodi-pvr-mediaportal-tvserver kodi-pvr-tvheadend-hts kodi-pvr-dvbviewer kodi-pvr-argustv
  kodi-pvr-iptvsimple kodi-audioencoder-vorbis kodi-audioencoder-flac
  kodi-audioencoder-lame
Recommended packages:
  libva-intel-vaapi-driver
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  kodi libgif7
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/23.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 38.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^(.*?)(\\)?\${ <-- HERE ([^{}]+)}(.*)$/ at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Question.pm line 72.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\${ <-- HERE ([^}]+)}/ at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Config.pm line 30.
Selecting previously unselected package libgif7:armhf.
(Reading database ... 39701 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgif7_5.1.4-0.4_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libgif7:armhf (5.1.4-0.4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package kodi.
Preparing to unpack .../kodi_2%3a17.3-1~jessie_all.deb ...
Unpacking kodi (2:17.3-1~jessie) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58) ...
Setting up libgif7:armhf (5.1.4-0.4) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u1) ...
Setting up kodi (2:17.3-1~jessie) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1~bpo8+1) ...
```

The installation works but kodi has strange freezes and can't open a video file (inconvenient for a media center...).

So I thought it might be because `libva-intel-vaapi-driver` is among recommended packages but not installed. I tried `sudo apt-get install libva-intel-vaapi-driver` and it gives me:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package libva-intel-vaapi-driver is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libva-intel-vaapi-driver' has no installation candidate
```

I found no way to install this package.

---

Another strange thing is that `libgif7`, a package installed with Kodi seems to be unproperly installed. When I do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` I get

```
Hit:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian jessie InRelease
Hit:2 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie InRelease
Hit:3 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  libgif7
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 downgraded, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/42.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^(.*?)(\\)?\${ <-- HERE ([^{}]+)}(.*)$/ at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Question.pm line 72.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\${ <-- HERE ([^}]+)}/ at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Config.pm line 30.
(Reading database ... 41693 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgif7_5.1.4-0.4_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libgif7:armhf (5.1.4-0.4) over (5.1.4-0.4) ...
Setting up libgif7:armhf (5.1.4-0.4) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u1) ...
```

If I repeat the command, I still get the same result, as if libgif7 cannot be properly installed.

I know this question is not very specific but if anyone has any clue on this, I would be happy to receive it.

Comment: `Hit:3 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch InRelease`
Why do you have debian 9 **stretch** repos in your `apt` list for your debian 8 **jessie**. This is causing all your problems, back-porting does not work this way.

Answer (score 1):

Your `apt-get update` command is suspicious, this line:

```
Hit:3 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch InRelease
```

This implies you added Debian 9 repositories (**stretch**) to `/etc/apt/sources.list` or in a separate file under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` . Since you are running Debian 8 (**jessie**) this is not good, and is liable to cause the sorts of issues you are having,

You should remove the offending list lines and try to recover your system, because you may have affected multiple packages.

```
apt-get update 
apt-get upgrade -y 
apt-get install -f
apt-get upgrade -y # for good measure
apt-get autoclean
... etc etc ...
```

Comment: This is because I have flashed raspbian from [nextcloudpi](https://ownyourbits.com/2017/02/13/nextcloud-ready-raspberry-pi-image/) which uses stretch packages. I tried to comment the line of stretch repo in my sources.list and it solved the libgif7 problem but Kodi still crashes when I try to read a video. This implies it is certainly related to the missing libva-intel-vaapi-driver package (which makes sense because it's a video acceleration driver).

Comment: @GustaveCoste its still the cause of your problem, that image is not compatible with KODI due to broken dependencies. This **is not** a valid way to back-port packages from stretch to jessie. There are probably a whole bunch of other tweaks to get the backport working for this hacky image that are getting in the way, I can tell you that `kodi` works out of the box on a standard jessie install.

Comment: so I think I will have to wait for Raspbian 9... Thank you for the answer

Comment: It is simple to compile software applications, drivers require additional work, the dependency for rpi for hardware probably isn't there yet in stretch, but the user software is compiled easily. You can try to explicitly install the version from jessie to see if it forces dependencies from jessie `apt-get install kodi=VERSION`